# .Net core 3.1 webapi dockerized, error in connection to database MySql (No dockerized)

Tags: mysql, .net, docker

I have a local project, that is a webapi (.net core 3.1) that connect with MySql (local server), good.
What I want to achieve, is do an image of my webapi (to pass then to production), I can do the image OK. But when I run the image, and I navigate via browser, I get the following error:

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[2004]
An error ocurred using the connection to database 'nameOfTable' on server 'localhost'

I didn't dockerize the mysql server, it's running as always, on local. I didn't change de user or the password... so I don't understand why I get this error.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you run a container with your Web API image, the container has its own network and also IP address. If your MySQL instance works your local machine, not on docker-engine, you must have to connect your local to your docker container somehow which is not suggested. Instead of that, you may run a MySQL container that uses your local MySQL data (you can mount a local folder to the container with -v/volumes).